# Define a new babel src (based in python)

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python, syntax-highlighting

I would like to write pieces of code (I don't need to evaluate it---yet---) of `Cadabra` [see the web page](http://cadabra.science/index.html) which is based in `python`. However, it uses the symbol `#` as part of the code.

How could I define a new babel language (based in python) which treats the `#` symbol differently?

The most important thing I want to keep is the code highlighting.

Comment: If there is no [major mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Major-Modes.html#Major-Modes) already for `cadabra` you may want to define one first before trying to set it up with `org-babel`.  If it's pretty close to python, you may be able to define a [derived mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Derived-Modes.html#Derived-Modes) and make the modifications you need, rather than writing the whole thing from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like cadabra is too much like python; but if all you wanted was python syntax highlighting without # as a comment, you can get it like this:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(define-derived-mode cadabra-mode python-mode "cadabra"
  ; make #a symbol constituent
  (modify-syntax-entry ?# "_" cadabra-mode-syntax-table))
#+END_SRC
```

## +RESULTS:

: cadabra-mode

See https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSyntaxTable for more info about the syntax table.